# How can i get errors silently in debug mode in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, debugging, firedac

I have a `TFDConection` running on a track every 10 seconds. It checks the connection to a remote PostgresSQL database. When I'm debugging, if the server goes down, the connection error is triggered constantly, disrupting my debugging process. How can I silently receive this error in Delphi?

Comment: When the exception comes up in the debugger, check/uncheck the checkbox that allows the debugger to ignore that exception class in the future. Then make sure your check catches the exception silently, and it should operate entirely in the background.

Comment: @HeartWare, thank you for the comment. I would like to validate the connection data in the database by returning a Boolean response or just the exception message without firing. The application could take care of firing after a certain number of attempts or just generate a log file. Not ignoring all errors.